# Sign Office documents (with a certificate) by code

Tags: java, ms-office, x509certificate

Is there any way to sign digitally an office document (Word, Excel, ...)? I've found how to sign PDF and XMLs documents, but I don't find anything about sign Word documents.

Thanks ;)

Comment: I would love to hear otherwise, but my assumption is that for security reasons this shouldn't be possible. What would stop a malicious program from signing itself?

Comment: @pook Of course, this is possible. Eg. our SecureBlackbox library lets you do this, and there exist some open-source projects that seem to try to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know Office uses XML Digital signature.

I've managed to implement reading/verifying of digital signatures of OpenOffice documents (which also use XML digital signature) by reading up on this:

http://www.w3.org/Signature

http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/08/08/xmldsig.html

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/xml/dig_signatures

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/xml/dig_signature_api

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/xmldsig/XMLDigitalSignature.html

Comment: There also exists binary format (older) which you can's sign with XML signing.